# System Included Font

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I just wrote an application for submission to the app store - and I'm reading on forums that using a font that is not included on a users machine will cause the whole app to crash. I used a font called Handwriting - Dakota, and I never installed it so I'm not 100% sure if it comes with Mac by default. Does anyone else running Mac 10.6 have this font?? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Best,
Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a clean (no non-developer apps) Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) install and this font isn't present. Additionally, it's not listed on the Wikipedia "[List of typefaces included with Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Mac_OS_X)" article either.

At a guess, it's most likely installed by iLife, iWork or similar.

Comment: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20014557-263.html?tag=untagged seems to back this up and lists 'Extra fonts include Coolvetica, Duality, Handwriting Dakota, Strenuous'.